# proxmox with multiple IP same subnet

Tags: proxmox

I have 3 server called Server-A, Server-B, Server-C

This are the IP: (for example)
Server-A (100.0.0.18/29)
Server-B (100.0.0.21/29)
Server-C (100.0.0.22/29)

in Server-A (100.0.0.18/29) I have two VM it called VM-1, VM-2

This are the IP:
VM-1 (100.0.0.19/29)
VM-2 (192.168.1.2/24)

My problem is:
1. The VM-1 and VM-2 can access the internet, but sometimes the VM-1 is timeout.
2. The VM-1 can't ping the Server-B or Server-C and vice versa.

This is the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 100.0.0.18
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway 100.0.0.17
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp

iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 100.0.0.18
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        up ip route add 100.0.0.19/32 dev vmbr1
```

How to make the VM-1 be able to ping from Server-B and Server-C and vice versa?